# Do I need an OS for a RaspberryPi Game Console?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to create a game console with my Raspberry Pi and create my own game with an SD Card. Do I need an OS loaded with games or can I insert various SD Cards with different games?

Comment: This is definitely not an appropriate SO question. But to answer this question: yes, if you want to do anything reasonable, but there is actually such thing as bare-metal programming for RPi.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the Raspberry Pi as a retro gaming console you will have to set it up. Go to the [RetroPie Download page](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/retropie-downloads/) and choose the appropriate download for your version of your Raspberry Pi. The go to the [RetroPi first installation](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/First-Installation) page and follow the directions. After you complete that you will have to move your roms to the Raspberry pi into the /RetroPie/roms folder on the SD card. I use a Raspberry Pi for classic gaming and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here.

RetroPi IS technically the OS. You then "add" games to it.
If you want to create your own games then you have plenty of options.
You can technically create your own games and export them as NES games to be read by the NES emulator. This is very difficult and requires you to use tools that might be out of scope for beginners. The advantage is that you can put them in eprom chips and play them on an actual NES.

I would instead try to create a game using something like PyGame and play them on a RaspberryPi. Yo uwon't need RetroPi for something like this. Instead you'd need an OS like Raspbian

Answer (score 0):

Yes definately. A raspberry pi without an operating system will not do anything. Its like asking a human to function without a brain. You should check out the retropie project. Its an operating system for the raspberry pi that lets you install roms and play the. You can even use controllers such as a ps3 controller. 
[Retropie](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/)

Answer (score 0):

Head to RetroPie to download the image to your computer. Then, flash it on to the MicroSD with either Win32DiskImager on Windows or  RPI-sd card builder on a Mac.

Have any other questions I can help with?